# Is wine server a client of X server?

Tags: x11, wine

Is   `wineserver` a client of X server?

I run some Windows GUI programs via wine, but

```
xlsclients  | grep -i wine
```

returns nothing.

How are the windows of the Windows GUI programs created then?

What are the relevant X clients?

```
$ xlsclients  
ocean  ibus-ui-gtk3
ocean  ibus-x11
ocean  update-notifier
ocean  xfce4-power-manager
ocean  xfce4-notifyd
ocean  nm-applet
ocean  chrome
ocean  lxterminal
ocean  firefox
ocean  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
ocean  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
ocean  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
ocean  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
ocean  evince
ocean  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
ocean  evince
ocean  lxsession
ocean  lxpolkit
ocean  lxpanel
ocean  pcmanfm
```

Thanks.

Comment: Note that `xlsclients` may not report all clients.  See, for example, https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xlsclients/issues/1

Comment: @StephenHarris I've already explained in another answer what `xlsclients` actually does: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486063/what-is-the-server-client-relationship-between-a-terminal-emulator-a-window-man/486189#486189

Comment: while wineserver may connect to the Xserver to handle some wm stuff, the windows are created by the programs themselves (as started by the wine wrapper). The wine libraries used by the program will translate to WinAPI calls into X11 requests.

Answer (score 1):

As [mosvy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/308316/mosvy) mentions, windows for programs run by Wine are created and managed by the applications themselves. You can see this by running a Windows GUI program, and running

```
xwininfo -wm
```

Click on the window you’re interested in, and `xwininfo` will output the window manager hints for that window, which should include the process identifier; you’ll see that the pid matches the application process, not Wine server.

The Wine server itself isn’t an X11 client, and isn’t linked to any X11 library. The X11 interface is managed (mostly) by `winex11.drv.so`, the Wine X11 driver. `lsof` will show you that `winex11.drv.so` is loaded by each Windows GUI client.