# Why doesn't glxgears show up in xlsclients?

Tags: linux, x11, xorg

```
$ glxgears -display :1
No protocol specified
Error: couldn't open display :1

$ glxgears -display :0
288 frames in 5.0 seconds = 57.491 FPS
292 frames in 5.0 seconds = 58.308 FPS
...
```

While `glxgears` is running, I ran `xlsclients` in a different terminal window:

```
$ xlsclients -display :0
alan-laptop  gnome-shell
alan-laptop  gsd-xsettings
alan-laptop  gsd-clipboard
alan-laptop  gsd-power
alan-laptop  gsd-color
alan-laptop  ibus-x11
alan-laptop  gsd-keyboard
alan-laptop  gsd-wacom
alan-laptop  gsd-media-keys
alan-laptop  firefox
```

---

System: Fedora 29, gnome-shell using Wayland.

```
$ rpm -q gnome-shell
gnome-shell-3.30.2-1.fc29.x86_64
$ rpm -q xorg-x11-server-Xwayland
xorg-x11-server-Xwayland-1.20.4-1.fc29.x86_64
$ rpm -q --whatprovides $(which xlsclients)
xorg-x11-utils-7.5-29.fc29.x86_64
$ rpm -q --whatprovides $(which glxgears)
glx-utils-8.4.0-1.fc29.x86_64
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486189/308316

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"`xlsclients` is a simple application which is listing the `WM_CLIENT_MACHINE` and `WM_COMMAND` properties set on top windows (ie. windows which are children of the root window or have a WM_STATE property)." -- [mosvy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486189/308316).

According to ICCCM, the properties must be set by the client.  I.e. if `glxgears` does not set them, it will not show up in `xlsclients`.

`WM_CLIENT_MACHINE` and `WM_COMMAND` are [marked as obsolete by ICCCM](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/ICCCM/icccm.html#obsolete_session_manager_conventions).  Also, it looks like they were only *required* as part of session management, which is not necessarily supported by all X clients.

This suggests `xlsclients` should be considered obsolete :-).

Comment: If `xlsclients` is obsolete, what is the replacement ?